# msmq multiple message types in a single queue

Tags: msmq

I'm planning on having a single queue receive ~100 different message types.

If I had only had 2 different types I'd do something like this

MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(_queue);
queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(CreateReportComand), typeof(CreateReportComand2)});

Is it craziness to pass XmlMessageFormatter an array of ~100 Types. And if not what is the best way to examine the received message to decide how to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WCF `MsmqIntegrationBinding` and handle messages of type `MsmqMessage<string>`. Then your handler method will receive the serialized message as a string and can do what you want with it after that.

Answer (score 0):

I preffer not to use Message.Formatter and Message.Body. Instead I use Message.BodyStream manualy serializing/deserializing my messages.
Type of the message can be embeded in serialized data (that is what I do) or you can put it on message header or on label.

Comment: I've started to use message.AppSpecific to hold an int I cast to an enum and seems to work ok