# How to handle multiple source queue message types

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, message-queue, race-condition

I am somewhat new to parallel programming in general, and am trying to understand how to handle a case where I have multiple types of messages on which my system waits.  This question is mostly intended to simply check my understanding.  My specific system is implemented using the Microsoft Concurrency Runtime (C++).

Having encountered these other two SO questions -

[Google Protocol Buffers, how to handle multiple message-Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27248075/1399272)

[msmq multiple message types in a single queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8166924/1399272)

It seems the general approach is to make a common message that represents all the different sub-types of messages.  Some metadata is included in the common message which determines the specific sub-type message.  Then all messages are piped through one queue; when read, the specific sub-type is determined from the message metadata and the appropriate action is performed.

However, in my particular application, I'd prefer to rather be able to use multiple queues specifically dedicated to each type of message, and then wait on all of them, handling whichever one obtains a message first.  However, I can see a couple of glaring read race conditions resulting from this approach -

1) It seems impossible to service messages of different types in the same order as they were separately queued.  Problem.

2) I can imagine two messages becoming available at the same time.  By whatever scheduling mechanism, one gets read, the other gets... discarded.  Fail.

These two issues alone make me quite willing to discard the latter approach.  But before I burninate my little thought experiment, is there anyone that can counter the two issues above in defense of multiple source queues?  Or is it indeed the case that only one queue with a common message format can be used?

Comment: 1. Why do you use several messages queues, if you want total order between them? Use single queue for that purpose. 2. `By whatever scheduling mechanism, one gets read, the other gets... discarded.` - Why a message could be discarded?

Comment: 1. Yes, you're right, it seems like that is an unavoidable failing of the system.  2.  Just speculating.  I could imagine the queues being implemented to set an event when they have read data.  It's possible to wait on multiple events.  But if multiple queues read at the same time, and multiple events are set, only one queue's message will be received by my system.  The other(s) will never be received, because the event(s) to indicate their being read have already been set.

Comment: 1. There are mechanisms (like timestamping) which allows to construct total order from several waitqueues. But using such mechanisms would .. effectively creates a single queue. 2. **Correct** mechanism for waiting on multiple sources shouldn't drop any message. Without a **concrete example**, the question seems for me unclear and discussion-like, which is not suitable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1. I've considered timestamping.  It wouldn't work since I would need to read the messages.  I would need a way of dequeuing them separately in the order they were separately enqueued. 2. I'm not sure there is a concrete example.  I'm with you, I think what I'm asking for is impossible, but I'm also new to this and would like to see if someone else with more experience has done successfully what I'm proposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to make multiple queues and have total order then you will need a ticket system maybe using an atomic int (all code is untested)

```
int GetTicket() {
  static std::atomic<int> myTicket { 0 };

  return myTicket++;
}
```

And then peel them off the queues in correct order.

But much easier to use a queue of `std::function<WhatEver>` either a lockless queue or if you want it simple a mutex protected queue, something like this

```
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void EnQueue(std::function<WhatEver> func) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  myQueue.push_back(std::move(func));
  ready = true;

  cv.notify_one();
}



void print_id (int id) {
  while(true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);

    auto func = myQueue.front();
    myQueue.pop();

    func();
  }
}
```

Comment: Accepting for the ticket idea.  I could theoretically use a separate ticket queue which would serve as the single main queue.  Reading off that would tell me which of the separate type queues should be read next.